# Shared library using a different version of another shared library to the main executable?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

**Problem**

- Say I've got a Linux executable MAIN that uses an old version of some shared library LIB.so (which it locates using LD_LIBRARY_PATH).
- I'd like MAIN to also use my library MYLIB.so, except this uses a newer version of LIB.so.
- MAIN and MYLIB.so both use functions that appear in both versions of LIB.so with the same name (but different implementations).

How do I get the application to also load the new version of LIB.so when it loads MYLIB.so?

**What doesn't seem to work**

I've tried compiling MYLIB.so with an RPATH option pointing to the new version of the library. However, while this correctly identifies the newer library when I run `ldd MYLIB.so`, when the application runs it only uses the old library implementation.

My compilation (using single file toy implementations for clarity) is as follows:

```
# compile old library implementation
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic library_old.cpp 
g++ -shared -o liblib.so library_old.o

# compile new library implementation
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic library_new.cpp 
g++ -shared -o new/liblib.so library_new.o

# compile my library against new liblib
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic my_library.cpp
g++ -L`pwd`/new -shared -Wl,-rpath,`pwd`/new -o libmine.so my_library.o -llib

# compile application against old liblib
g++ -L`pwd` -Wall -Werror -o main main.cpp -llib -lmine
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
```

Comment: You may need [`-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld). [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) may also be useful, but its a pain to ask users to type it. Things should "just work" so they don't have to do things like `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Won't LD_PRELOAD have the opposite problem? I.e. the executable would now pick up the new version of the library too? What I would like (if it's even possible) is for the executable to still use the old library while mylib.so uses the new library.

Comment: *"What I would like ... is for the executable to still use the old library while mylib.so uses the new library"* - You can't do that on Linux. Its a flat namespace. The first library the link loader finds with the symbol wins. All symbols are used from the winner (assuming the symbols are present).

Comment: @jww OK, thanks. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: I think what you should (must?) do is provide a `MYLIB.so` that is backwards compat with the original lib so all calls can route through `MYLIB.so`. Then, have `MYLIB.so` `dlopen` `OLDLIB.so` and then route calls into the old lib as required. You can find symbols in the old lib with `dlsym`. Its similar to what the Linux crowd calls [interpositioning](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+shared+object+interpositioning).

Comment: By the way, Linux variants matter when interposing. Red Hat and Fedora need one set of flags when `dlopen`'ing a shared object, while Debian and Ubuntu need another set of flags when `dlopen`'ing a shared object. You will need either `RTLD_GLOBAL` or both `RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY`. And Android may need `RTLD_LOCAL`. Here's how I do it in a test program for the Crypto++ library: [Crypto++ shared object loading via dlopen](https://pastebin.com/jTNy5yGi). Crypto++ has an added wrinkle of different names on Red Hat and Debian.